# how to read and and perform calculations on fix point value with tcl

Tags: tcl, point

I would like to read this file below with tcl:

```
        BEGIN
        %Time (real)        HG (real)
        !Time               HG

        -0.000110400001          0.6
        -0.000110399901          0.6
        -0.000110399801          0.6
        -0.000110399701          0.6
        -0.000110399601         0.55
        -0.000110399501          0.5
        -0.000110399401         0.45
        -0.000110399301          0.4
        -0.000110399201         0.45
        -0.000110399101          0.5
        -0.000110399001         0.55
        -0.000110398901          0.6
```

For each Time column, i would like to increment by +0.000110400001 and write this result in new file. i would like other column doesn't be modified and copy as such.

I began to coding (see below), i can open and read the value but I don't how to convert string in fix point and make addition on this. If anyone help me that would be nice.

```
set inVector  [lindex $argv 0]

puts "input vector : $inVector"

set filename "resultat.mdf"

set fileId [open $filename "w"]

set PROCESSING_FILE [open "$inVector" r]

while {[eof $PROCESSING_FILE]==0} {
    set string [gets $PROCESSING_FILE]
    if {[string index $string 3] != "B"} {
        if {[string index $string 3] != "%"} {
            if {[string index $string 3] != "!"} {
                foreach line $string {
                    puts "input value : $line"
                }
            } else {
              puts $fileId $string
            }

        } else {
            puts $fileId $string
        }
    } else {
      puts $fileId $string
    }
}


close $PROCESSING_FILE
close $fileId
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please paste both `testvector` and `code i did` into the question to make it easier to copy-and-paste into an answer.

Comment: The [`math::exact`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/math/exact.md) package from tcllib might be helpful.

Comment: pictures of text will not help us to help you.

Comment: It is done, i put the code into the question. Tanks for patience , i'm new in SO

Answer (score 0):

For lines with digits on, you could probably read them like this:

```
scan $string "%f %f" time hg
```

If that returns 2 (for two fields processed) you've successfully read two (floating point) numbers from that line. Otherwise, the line is something else. This leads to code like this (with some standard line-by-line idioms that must've been written up already in some other question):

```
# Skipping all the code for opening files

# While we successfully read a line from the input file
while {[gets $PROCESSING_FILE line] >= 0} {
    # Attempt to parse two floats (with at least one whitespace between) out of line
    if {[scan $line "%f %f" time hg] == 2} {
        # Action to take on a matched line
        puts "input line: '$line' time:$time HG:$hg"
    } else {
        # Action to take on an unmatched line
        puts $fileId $line
    }
}

# Skipping the code for closing files
```

For files with truly fixed width fields, you use `string range` to pick out pieces of the line and then attempt to parse those (or you write a messy regular expression and use `regexp`). Those tend to need more tuning to the data.